# Why does before_action :authorize fail with 'wrong number of arguments'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails, pundit

I have set up Pundit together with Devise for authorization on my application. In one of my controllers, I have `before_action :authorize`.

I then have the following test:

```
describe SomeController do
  before(:each) do
    login_user(FactoryGirl.create(:user, :user_type => :admin))
  end

  describe "GET index" do
    it "it retrieves the index" do
      something = FactoryGirl.create(:Something)
      get :index
      assigns(:something).should eq([something])
    end
  end
end
```

I receive the error:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

The login helper is fairly straight forward:

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_user(user)
    if user.nil?
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    end

    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    sign_in user
  end
end
```

**Update:**
Stacktrace:

```
Failure/Error: get :index
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/pundit-0.2.3/lib/pundit.rb:62:in `authorize'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in `block in make_lambda'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:160:in `call'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:160:in `block in halting'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionview-4.1.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:595:in `process'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:64:in `process'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:19:in `block in process'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:72:in `catch'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:72:in `_catch_warden'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:19:in `process'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:495:in `get'
     # ./spec/controllers/SomeController_spec.rb:31:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:114:in `instance_eval'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:114:in `block in run'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_eval_with_args'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `instance_eval_with_args'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:179:in `call'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:179:in `run'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_eval_with_args'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `instance_eval_with_args'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:108:in `call'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:108:in `run'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:446:in `run_hook'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:340:in `run_around_each_hooks'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:256:in `with_around_each_hooks'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:111:in `run'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:390:in `block in run_examples'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `map'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `run_examples'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:371:in `run'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `block in run'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `map'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `run'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `block in run'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `map'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `run'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `map'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block in run'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:58:in `report'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in `run'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
     # /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Comment: Tell us where the error occurs in the code you show.

Comment: The error occurs when running the unit test.

Comment: On which line of what file (and what does that correspond to in the code you show)?

Comment: Sorry for not getting the precise question :) it is in the get :index line, where it fails.

Comment: I presume it isn't `get` itself failing, so please show the entire backtrace.

Comment: Sorry, stacktrace is now there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pundit's `authorize` method is not intended to be called as a `before_action`. `before_action` calls a method with no arguments, and `authorize` takes a model object and an optional permission name. That's why you're getting the error you are.

You're not showing enough of the relevant code for me to see what you should do next, but I suggest getting Pundit to work in your controller action before pulling it out into a callback.

There is an example of the correct use of `authorize` here: https://github.com/elabs/pundit

Comment: You were right the error was because I was using a before_action. I had my mindset on Devise, instead of using after_action :verify_authorized. Thanks at lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can define a private helper method in your controller(or in the `application_controller` if you will use it in all the controllers) which calls `authorize current_user`, and then call the private method `before_action`. Like this:

```
    private
    def perform_authorization
      authorize current_user
    end
```

and then call it as a `before_action` :

```
    before_action :perform_authorization
```